# ArUco marker Detection ids None

Tags: python, opencv, augmented-reality, aruco

Hey everyone i recently started to learn arUco markers for detecting a specific point in image so i generate a simple marker with id 10 but when i tried to detect it with my python code

```
import math
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco

img = cv2.imread("temp.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_5X5_250)

parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

# print(parameters)

corners, ids, _ = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
# cv2.imshow("img", img)
# ids = 10
print(ids)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

i didn't get the ids instead of number it shows none and also value of corner is empty list
after that i copy a code from the internet to check weather the detection is working or not but still that code gives me the same output
here i have shared two output images first one is from my above code and second one is from the code that i copied from internet

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's a 4x4 marker, not 5x5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [ArUco markers generator](https://chev.me/arucogen/) site that by default generate a 4x4 aruco marker size.

Using your image [image]

I got [[0]] by changing

`aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_5X5_250)`

to

`aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_250)`